# Is there a way to jump directly to the page position when you click on the scroll bar?

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

On Google Chrome (well, I'm using Brave), preessing on the scroll bar will only do a pgup or pgdn in the direction towards where I click. I want it to jump directly to the page position corresponding to where my mouse is on the scroll bar when I click on the scroll bar, as if I had dragged the scroll bar all the way over there.

I looked at this Google support thread ([1](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/48602544/click-to-jump-on-feature-scrollbar-not-working?hl=en)), and one poster suggested disabling the "Compositor threaded scrollbar scrolling" flag. This had no effect. I tried disabling/enabling different combinations of any flags related to "scrollbar" with no success. Another poster suggested the workaround (insofar as I would ideally like to modify the default behavior of clicking the scroll bar) of, on Mac, holding the Option modifier while clicking. I'm not on a Mac.

Comment: While links are useful your question should include all the info necessary to answer.  I the i8nfo is relevant edit your question to include it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Holding Shift in Windows or Option in Mac while clicking on the scroll bar will make the scroll bar jump directly to where you're cursor was.